# In UIActionSheet the cancel button not showing for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

In my application when I click on change image it's asks UIActionsheet with three actions take photo ,choose from library and cancel.Take photo ,choose from library are showing but cancel didn't showing where is the problem.
this is my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
         [super viewDidLoad];
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..."
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from library", nil];
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: you have `{` twice, and `}` once.

Comment: This code is not the problem. I have created a new project and used exactly your code (only one `{`). It works as expected. I get an actionsheet with 3 buttons: "take photo" and "choose from library" in light gray, and a "cancel" button in dark grey with the title "Select Image from..."

Comment: did you used tabBar in your app ?

Comment: not the braces issue.

Comment: No tabbar, a completly clean, single view based project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because...I think you are using the default view size -Retina 4 full screen as your view size...Just try and change your view size to Retina 3.5 full screen from the Attributes inspector...!!!

Comment: The code in the question works for iPhone, iPhone 3,5" and iPhone 4" (tested)

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..." 
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from library", nil];

    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: Couple things, you don't need to cast id to the delegate, destructive buttons aren't the same as cancel buttons, and this code still maintains the setting of style to one option, then immediately setting it to another.

Comment: @Abhijith I was tried It's throwing exception 2013-07-29 16:21:48.273 TestIGate[14936:c07] actionSheet
2013-07-29 16:21:49.087 TestIGate[14936:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9f012 0x10dce7e 0x2249d9 0x4278 0x416d 0x4012c1 0x10f0705 0x27920 0x278b8 0xe8671 0xe8bcf 0xe7d38 0x5733f 0x57552 0x353aa 0x26cf8 0x1bfadf9 0x1bfaad0 0x1c14bf5 0x1c14962 0x1c45bb6 0x1c44f44 0x1c44e1b 0x1bf97e3 0x1bf9668 0x2465c 0x28fd 0x2825)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: are u not using ARC for your project??

Comment: Am using ARC for my project

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don´t think there is a reason to cast any object to id, ever.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the alternative methods for presenting an action sheet in the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). However, you may want to try using one of the following (if you have a toolbar)

```
– showFromBarButtonItem:animated:
– showFromToolbar:
```

Additionally, using the following

```
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
```

will only ever result in the action sheets style being default.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this link](http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=136&Itemid=27).

And you can refer below code also, it may help you:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
    {

    UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from library", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

    }
```

Comment: Please check out the above link which i have given. its an example of UIActionSheet

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is not with your code. Maybe you are using the wrong method to display your  UIActionSheet.

A UIActionSheet can be displayed with following methods:

```
– showFromTabBar:
– showFromToolbar:
– showInView:
– showFromBarButtonItem:animated:
– showFromRect:inView:animated:
```

take a look at [Apple's UIActionSheet reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Since you use a TabBar, the Cancel button may also be below. I would test that too.

Comment: Maybe you can try: `[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];`. This might solve the issue with the TabBar, in case that's the problem.